# How to read attribute values from XML and combine them to one string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

**EDIT:** The proposed answers don't work for me so far. Maybe my example was a bit misleading. I have updated the XML as well as the expected string for reference. I can have multiple occurrences of the nodes with different levels and in each level I can have one or many child's.

I have a XML file with the following structure:

```
<VariableCollection>
    <Variable Name="Level1">
         <Variable Name="Level2">
               <Variable Name="Level3">
                   <Variable Name="Level4"/>
                   <Variable Name="Level41"/>
               </Variable>
         </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="Level11">
         <Variable Name="Level21">
               <Variable Name="Level31">
                   <Variable Name="Level41"/>
                   <Variable Name="Level42"/>
                   <Variable Name="Level43"/>
               </Variable>
         </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="Level1">
          <Variable Name="Level2">
               <Variable Name="Level3"/>
          </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="Level11">
          <Variable Name="Level21">
               <Variable Name="Level31"/>
          </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="Level1">
          <Variable Name="Level2"/>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="Level11">
          <Variable Name="Level21"/>
    </Variable>
</VariableCollection>
```

So I have nodes with different structured sub levels/child nodes.
What I want to do is to read the entire file using LINQ to XML and get one string  per "main-node" that is created from the attribute 'Name' of each "sub-node". So the result should look like:

```
string1 = "Level1.Level2.Level3.Level4"
string11 = "Level1.Level2.Level3.Level41"

string2 = "Level11.Level21.Level31.Level41"
string22 = "Level11.Level21.Level31.Level42"
string23 = "Level11.Level21.Level31.Level43"

string3 = "Level1.Level2.Level3"
string3 = "Level11.Level21.Level31"

string4 = "Level1.Level2"
string5 = "Level11.Level21"
```

My problem is that I have no idea how I can get this done.
Can anybody show me an example how I can get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used "bottom-up" approach. The first step is to find variables which don't have nested elements (`lastLvl` in code). The second step is to traverse back to root and concatenate names. The following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Collections;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var @s = 
@"<VariableCollection>
    <Variable Name='Level1'>
         <Variable Name='Level2'>
               <Variable Name='Level3'>
                   <Variable Name='Level4'/>
                   <Variable Name='Level41'/>
               </Variable>
         </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name='Level11'>
         <Variable Name='Level21'>
               <Variable Name='Level31'>
                   <Variable Name='Level41'/>
                   <Variable Name='Level42'/>
                   <Variable Name='Level43'/>
               </Variable>
         </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name='Level1'>
          <Variable Name='Level2'>
               <Variable Name='Level3'/>
          </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name='Level11'>
          <Variable Name='Level21'>
               <Variable Name='Level31'/>
          </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name='Level1'>
          <Variable Name='Level2'/>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name='Level11'>
          <Variable Name='Level21'/>
    </Variable>
</VariableCollection>";
```

```
        var xml = XElement.Parse(@s);

        var lastLvl = xml.Descendants("Variable").Where(x => !x.HasElements);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lastLvl));

        var names = lastLvl.Select(x => String.Join(".", x.AncestorsAndSelf("Variable").Select(e=>(string)e.Attribute("Name")).Reverse()));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, names));
    }
}
```

generates the output:

lastLevel:

```
<Variable Name="Level4" />
<Variable Name="Level41" />
<Variable Name="Level41" />
<Variable Name="Level42" />
<Variable Name="Level43" />
<Variable Name="Level3" />
<Variable Name="Level31" />
<Variable Name="Level2" />
<Variable Name="Level21" />
```

names:

```
Level1.Level2.Level3.Level4
Level1.Level2.Level3.Level41
Level11.Level21.Level31.Level41
Level11.Level21.Level31.Level42
Level11.Level21.Level31.Level43
Level1.Level2.Level3
Level11.Level21.Level31
Level1.Level2
Level11.Level21
```

try a [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gNJulD) fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
var root = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var strings = root.Root.Elements()
    .Select(e => String.Join(".", e.DescendantsAndSelf().Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("Name"))))
    .ToArray();
```

Here I loop through the immediate children of the root element `<VariableCollection>` with [`XElement.Elements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx), then for each element recursively descent its element hierarchy with [`DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346989(v=vs.110).aspx) to pick out the `Name` attributes in a nested query, then combine the values with [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QnaU0s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XElement` to parse and traverse the documents like this:

```
string xml = @"
<VariableCollection>
    <Variable Name=""Level1"">
         <Variable Name=""Level2"">
               <Variable Name=""Level3"">
                   <Variable Name=""Level4""/>
               </Variable>
         </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name=""Level1"">
          <Variable Name=""Level2"">
               <Variable Name=""Level3""/>
          </Variable>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name=""Level1"">
          <Variable Name=""Level2""/>
    </Variable>
</VariableCollection>
";

var root  = XElement.Parse(xml);

var stringList = new List<string>();
foreach (var child in root.Elements())
{
    string value = child.DescendantsAndSelf()
        .Select(i => i.Attribute("Name").Value)
        .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "." + b);

    stringList.Add(value);
}

foreach (var str in stringList)
    Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
```

If you want to load from a file, then us this code:

```
var root = XElement.Load("filepath");
```